# Calculating AICc for regression with ARMA errors

Tags: r, regression, time-series, aic, lags

I am unable to manually calculate the AICc for a regression with ARMA errors.

I would appreciate any help, such as: (1) pointing out what I am doing wrong or not doing; (2) advice on a textbook that shows the correct method; (3) a corrected version of what I am trying to do.

### Context

As part of my effort to understand the automated R functions I use, I am trying to manually reproduce an AICc test value from [Hyndman and Athanasopoulos (2018, chapter 9.6)](https://otexts.com/fpp2/lagged-predictors.html).

The R code to reproduce Hyndman and Athanasopoulos's results is as follows:

```
# Lag and Arrange Predictor Variables
Advert <- cbind(
  AdLag0 = insurance[,"TV.advert"],
  AdLag1 = stats::lag(insurance[,"TV.advert"],-1)) %>%
  head(NROW(insurance))

# Arrange Regression Variables
y <- insurance[4:40,1] 
x1 <- Advert[4:40,1] # AdLag0
x2 <- Advert[4:40,2] # AdLag1

# Automated Regression with ARMA Errors
auto.arima(y, xreg=Advert[4:40,1:2],
           stationary = TRUE)
```

The above code produces the following test values:

```
AIC=58.09   AICc=60.02   BIC=66.14
```

The AICc is 60.02.

### My Attempt to Calculate AICc Manually

First, I found an equation of an AICc for a linear regression:

[image: AICc equation for a linear regression. Source: YouTube.]

Second, I reproduced the AICc equation in R:

```
# key AICc Equation Variables
n <- NROW(y)
sse <- fit$residuals^2
k <- length(fit$coefficients)

# AICc Elements:
# (1) Regression Approximation
reg_approx <- (n*log(sum(sse/n)))

# (2) Pi Element
pe <- ((n*(log(2*pi)))+n)

# (3) AICc Penalty Term
pt <- 2*k+((2*k*(k+1))/(n-k-1))

# Assemble AICc Equation:
man_aicc <- reg_approx + pt + pe
```

Third, I tested the “by hand” AICc equation using the same test data as above, but without ARMA errors:

```
y <- insurance[4:40,1] 
x1 <- Advert[4:40,1] # AdLag0
x2 <- Advert[4:40,2] # AdLag1

fit <- lm(y~x1+x2)
```

I used the residuals from `fit` to get a manual AICc test value of 101.5594.

To check my AICc test value, I used `auto.arima` with the same regression model, and tested for the best ARMA p and q values:

```
test <- auto.arima(y, xreg=Advert[4:40,1:2],
                   stationary=TRUE,
                   ic = "aicc", 
                   trace = TRUE)
```

The `auto.arima` AICc test value with ARIMA(0,0,0) is 102.4282, which is only 0.8688 greater than my AICc test result.

So, I concluded my manual version—which I think is essentially a regression with ARIMA(0,0,0)—was relatively comparable with `auto.arima` and was in working order.

### Assumed Point of Failure

I tried to incorporate ARMA errors into my manual AICc equation with an ARIMA(1,0,1), which the Hyndman and Athanasopoulos example code used above:

```
fit <- lm(y~x1+x2)
arma_model <- Arima(fit$residuals, 
                    order = c(1,0,1), 
                    include.mean = FALSE)
# ARMA Errors:
arma_resid <- residuals(arma_model)
```

I constructed the same manual AICc as shown above, but replaced the `sse` var with the following:

```
sse <- arma_resid^2
```

The manual AICc test produced the following value: 74.53657.

This manual AICc value is much larger than the `AICc=60.02` from the Hyndman and Athanasopoulos example above.

## Conclusion

I assume there is some fundamental thing I am misunderstanding about regression with ARMA errors or the AICc function. Or, perhaps, it is something else entirely that I have missed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that stand out to me. Your definition of SSE and the Regression Approximation equations where you summed sse/n and not sse.

1. The equation asks for SSE however you plugged in SSR.

- SSE = Sum of the squared errors
- SSR = Sum of the squared residuals

What you did was

```
sse <- fit$residuals^2
```

It should really be:

```
sse <- sum((y - mean(y))^2)
```

2. Then

```
reg_approx <- n*log(sse/n)
```

Try that please

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a go this evening or sometime tomorrow. Many thanks!